# Congruent chords in a circle?

Tags: geometry

So if I were to construct four congruent chords within a circle that are connected at endpoints would it create a square? And would that prove that all of the angles are 90 degrees?

Answer (score 0):

It would prove that all angles are $90$ degrees. I say this because alone, any four lines, or in this case any four chords of equal length can only create a square. Hence that a square has for $90$-degree angles and has all congruent sides.

Comment: It is important that the four segments have endpoints on a circle, maybe you should include that condition. Otherwise four equal segments joined at ends can collapse (i.e. not a "rigid" figure).

Answer (score 0):

For each chord draw the triangle connecting the center to its endpoints. Then these four triangles are congruent by SSS, since each has two radii and one of the equal chords as sides. This means the angles at the center are the same for each, call that $\theta.$ Next, the condition that the four chords join up imply that $4\theta=360$ so $\theta=90$, and then since these are isosceles the other two angles are $45$ in each triangle. Finally two adjacent triangles fill out a $90$ degree angle at each corner of the four sided figure made by the chords.